# Should I be using Celery/Redis in my Django application?

Tags: python, django, web, redis, celery

I have a Django application that is designed to be used as a companion tool for sportsbooks or DFS sites. I am largely self-taught, so I have been adopting a more "go with what works" approach and then going back to revise my methods as I learn better ways to create the app.

I have several tables from scraped data in CSV format that I import into my DB with shell scripts. For example, one table is for starting lineups, and another is for player stats. I then have methods set up in my models.py to take that imported data and turn it into data that I want to use.

I found out quickly that trying to call a large group of objects and the values from their method functions was not at all efficient. I get the data I need via the methods because a lot of it is based on data from multiple tables (for example, I might want the start time of a game from the starting lineups table for a player object.)

The current solution that I have is to use Threading to run a function every few minutes to calculate the results of every method for the player objects, then storing that as a list of dictionaries in a variable, and importing that variable in the relevant views (rather than setting the variable to the objects themselves.) I'm sure there's a million ways this is a bad idea. I am still just learning.

I have heard some things about Celery and Redis, and think those could be used to do what I'm doing (but the right way, of course.) Am I on the right track? If so, are there any resources that you have found useful in using Celery/Redis?

Thank you for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of Redis and Celery is that they allow to run tasks in the background, while letting your Django app to continue running

example, lets say I want to create 1000 new random users (bad idea, but it's for concept). If I run it normally, my app will have to wait for the function to end before executing following lines, which means users will have to wait

but with celery

tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def create_random_user_accounts(total):
    for i in range(total):
        username = 'user_{}'.format(
            get_random_string(10, string.ascii_letters))
        email = "{}@example.com".format(username)
        password = get_random_string(50)
        User.objects.create_user(
            username=username, email=email, password=password)
    return "{} random users created with sucess!".format(total)
```

randomview.py

```
class GenerateRandomUserView(FormView):
    template_name = 'generate_random_users.html'
    form_class = GenerateRandomUserForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        total = form.cleaned_data.get('total')
        create_random_user_accounts.delay(total)
        messages.success(
            self.request, "We are generating your users! Wait a moment and refresh")
        return redirect('users_list')
```

in this example, my user will be redirected to users-list, where on each refresh they'll be able to see the new users being created without having to wait for all of them to be created

TLDR:
When dealing with computationally taxing methods that might affect user intractability, I would advise to use celery and redis

you do need two more servers though. One to run redis, and the other to run celery and of course the one running your Django app

Comment: note you can run redis, celery and django (gunicorn or other) all together on one server.

Comment: Do you have a link to a tutorial for that?

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/asynchronous-tasks-in-django-with-redis-and-celery